# How to map EnumOrdinalTypeHandler for mybatis-spring-boot?

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am now using Mybatis with spring-boot. I didn't add `mybatis-config.xml`. I make all configurations for datasource and mybatis via `application.properties` from instructions of 
[mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/) as below

```
### Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mywebsite;catalogName=mywebsite
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

### Mybatis Configurations ###
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.mycom.myproducts.mywebsite.config.bean
mybatis.type-handlers-package=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler
mybatis.mapperLocations=classpath:mybatis/mapper/**/*.xml
mybatis.configuration.default-fetch-size=100
mybatis.configuration.default-statement-timeout=30
```

The problem is mybatis can't map for my enum types and the error show

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'gender' from result set.  
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.mycom.myproducts.mywebsite.config.bean.config.UserBean.Gender.0
```

This can be fixed by `mybatis-config.xml` with

```
    <typeHandlers>
       <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler" javaType="com.mycom.myproducts.mywebsite.config.bean.config.UserBean$Gender"/>
    </typeHandlers>
```

but I don't know how can this be done by `application.properties` file ?

Comment: The `type-handlers-package` is for custom type handlers (you gave a class, not a package BTW). Instead, create a setter method `setGender(int i)` overloading `setGender(Gender g)` and loop through your enum (if/else for Gender) to find the correct enum with the correct id. MyBatis will call `setGender(int i)` instead of using enums. Sorry I don't know how to use a custom type handler with annotations yet... which is how I found this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
package com.example.typehandler;
@MappedTypes({Gender.class})
public class GenderTypeHandler extends EnumOrdinalTypeHandler {}
```

---

```
mybatis.type-handlers-package=com.example.typehandler
```

---

```
    @Select(...)
    @Results(value = {
             @Result(property="gender", column="gender", typeHandler="com.example.typehandler.Gender"),
             ...
```

The `typeHandler` in the `@Result` may be unnecessary if you use `@MappedTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a package instead of the TypeHandler class directly.

So you could use it as next:

```
mybatis.type-handlers-package=org.apache.ibatis.type
```

---

The manual page says **type-handlers-package** get package to search for type aliases.

> **type-handlers-package** Packages to search for type handlers. (Package
>   delimiters are ",; \t\n")

Comment: Hello ! Thank you bro ... I think this seems to work but I got exceptions
`Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Unable to find a usable constructor for class org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler` and 
`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler.<init>()` . What should I do ? regards.

Comment: The MyBatis type handlers are already the default for enums. This isn't the problem. The `type-handlers-package` is for custom type handlers. Instead, create a setter method `setGender(int i)` overloading `setGender(Gender g)` and loop through your enum (if/else for Gender) to find the correct enum with the correct id. MyBatis will call `setGender(int i)` instead of using enums. Sorry I don't know how to use a custom type handler with annotations yet... which is how I found this.